# How to import a file with a wrong header and a right one at an unknown row location

Tags: r

I have a file that has headers but they may not be in the first line (and if they are they may not be the right headers). How can I deal with this?

```
df<-data.frame(a=seq(0:10))
colname(df)<-("The Wrong Header")
df[4,1]<-"TheRightHeader" #This is one concatenated string because I couldn't work out how to add spaces using this input method
```

To know whether the first header is correct or not, the two rows after it always contain a 0.
The real nasty data is here (available until 27th Sept):

https://leeds365-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/cenmk_leeds_ac_uk/EQFIeY_U1f5MrC5B_YdqChkBrNSxQ_6vvVHZ_NR-6kNTYg?e=Jsb918

A desired output would be:

```
colnames(df)<-"The Right Header"
```

Comment: can't access your data without login. Also, could you provide your desired output from your example?

Comment: You could use `readLines` to fetch the first few lines, do a test where the header is located and use that information when importing the whole file via `read.table` or what have you.

Comment: Thanks Heck for pointing this out. I've uploaded it somewhere which is freely available

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Oh I had not seen readlines before, thanks!